# Jenkins tests reports analyzer integration with catch

Tags: c++, testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I've recently started working with Jenkins to automatically build my c++ project and run my tests (I'm using catch.cpp).

I wanted some sort of a table of test run time and status and that led me to the "Test Results Analyzer" Plugin for Jenkins.

I have my builds run like this: 
[image: running the tests]

And you can see they actually run in the console output:
[image: build console output]

finally, my test results analyzer plugin shows nothing: 
[image: no tests on the plugin page]

It looks like the plugin does not recognize that these are my tests. Which is reasonable since I've only told jenkins to execute these commands and i don't think it's smart enough to understand these are the tests to report. But i could not find how to tell "Test Reports Analyzer" what are the tests it needs to report.

My question is how do i get a table of tests like in the Plugins webpage:

[Tests Reports Analyzer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin)

**Solution:**

Jenkins needs a Junit format xml file of the test results.

specifically, in Catch.cpp this is achieved by the "-r junit" command line option.

after this i needed to configure jenkins to "Publish JUnit test result report" post-build action and git it a path to the output xml file i create with my "make test" command.

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer and accept it? That way others looking for the same issue can find a solution here.

Comment: my user is forbidden from answering questions, it's very frustrating...

Comment: I quoted your solution and gave you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution provided by OP:

> Jenkins needs a Junit format xml file of the test results.
>
> specifically, in Catch.cpp this is achieved by the "-r junit" command line option.
>
> after this i needed to configure jenkins to "Publish JUnit test result report" post-build action and git it a path to the output xml file i create with my "make test" command.